# What can be stored as member variables for Android fragments without worrying about them being freed up?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm just starting out with Android development and I'm noticing that certain references stored as member variables in fragments get freed up by Android if I leave the app (without shutting it down) and then coming back after a while. One example is references to activity action bar.

Is it generally acceptable to store references to things like views, adapters, action bar as member variables or should the references be queried fresh each time they are needed?

Comment: This is kind of like asking for a way to cause memory leak. As much as I can suggest, don't store reference to any UI components. Android fragment do keep the state of the UI, however. Learn the lifecycle of `Activity` and `Fragment` and you will get a better idea of what should not be done.

Answer (score 1):

What the user perceives as the same instance of an activity or fragment may not actually be the same instance.  The Android framework may destroy it whenever it goes into the background or backstack.  Activities and fragments both have methods called [`onSaveInstanceState`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) that you can override to save values that will be passed back to the recreated instance.

As haike00 noted in a comment, you should avoid saving references to fragments, activities, or views this way because those components may themselves be destroyed and recreated, and you would then be leaking the old instances.

Comment: I see, this makes sense. So I guess the reference of anything's that's constructed within the fragment can be safely stored, since destroying the fragment would also completely destroy these references. But anything that's not from the fragment itself should not be stored.